# Find number of unused disk bays on a Sun/Oracle server running Solaris

Tags: solaris, solaris-10, sun

How can you find the number of unused disk bays on a Sun/Oracle server running Solaris? I have a Oracle T3-1 server with four disks. Now I would like to find out how many disks more I can insert. According to the specs a T3-1 server has 8 or 16 disk bays, but I don't know how many mine has...

Best regards,
Andreas

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to check the HW via ILOM/ALOM with `show /HOST` or `showplatform [–v]` also `showfru` could be useful.